Scrolling to lazyColumn item with the item key and not the item index
I built a complex lazyColumn composable that mimic a card (indeed, I need to have a list of cards containing potentialy many items each, and nesting a LazyColumn in a Card is not possible (due to the "Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height contraints" issue). So my composable gets a list of data items of this kind :
data class CardsState(val cards: ImmutableList<Card>)

data class Card(
    val header: String,
    val items: ImmutableList<CardItem>,
)

In the LazyColumn, it can takes several LazyListScope.item to draw one CardItem.
So far so good.
But I also need sometimes to scroll to a specific CardItem. Unfortunately, I can't use the LazyListState.animateScrollToItem(index: Int) function as it takes the item index as parameter, and i can't tell what is the lazyColumn item index I need as it can be tricky to calculate.
The best for me would be to have a LazyListState.animateScrollToItem(key: Any) as all my LazyColumn  items have a unique key that I can pass as a parameter to my state like this :
interface CollectionItem {
    val key: Any?
}

fun CollectionItem.makeKey(): String = buildString {
    append(javaClass.name)
    key?.let { append("_$it") }
}

data class CardsState(
    val cards: ImmutableList<Card>,
    val scrollToItemWithKey: Any?, // The key of the lazyColumn item I want to scroll to
)

data class Card(
    val header: String,
    val items: ImmutableList<CardItem>,
) : CollectionItem {
    override val key: String = header
}

sealed class CardItem : CollectionItem {
    data class CardItemTypeA(/* some parameters */) : CardItem()
    data class CardItemTypeB(/* some others*/) : CardItem()
}

@Composable
fun MyContent(cardsState: CardsState) {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyColumn(state = scrollState) {
        cardsState.cards.forEach { card ->
            item(key = "${card.makeKey()}_top") { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) }
            item(key = "${card.makeKey()}_header") { Header(card.header) }
            items(items = card.items, key = { it.makeKey() }) {
                when (it) {
                    is CardItem.CardItemTypeA -> ComposeCardItemTypeA()
                    is CardItem.CardItemTypeB -> ComposeCardItemTypeB()
                }
                item(key = "${card.makeKey()}_bottom") { CardBottomLayout() }
            }
        }
    }
}

But obviously this scrollToItemWithKey doesn't exist. Of course I could "calculate" the lazycolumnIndex knowing how it is built, but that makes my calculation made in a ViewModel dependent on the way the view is built on the compose side, and can be tricky, especially if I want to add other composable within my main LazyColumn. Is there another way for me to achieve this scrolling ?

Please [edit] your question and also add how you create your LazyColumn. What is the list of items? What is the key? Do you even use the scrollState in your LazyColumn?


Of course I could "calculate" the lazycolumnIndex knowing how it is built, but that makes my calculation made in a ViewModel dependent on the way the view is built on the compose side

That calculation doesn't belong in the view model, it should be done somewhere near/in the LazyColumn because it is dependent on how that is constructed. Either create a mapping of CardItem to its index in the final LazyColumn and make sure it is only recalculated when cardsState.cards changes (like, remember(cardsState.cards) { ... } and use this mapping to retrieve the precalculated index when you need to scroll, or calculate the index on demand when you want to execute the scroll.
